# What is Synchronous XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I was testing and see if I can use javascript to load .js  after the document is ready, and got this warning message from chrome:

"Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience."

My codes are like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var s=$('<script src="test.js"></script>');
    $('body').append(s);
});
```

My questions are:

1) In this case, what is considered a "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest"? I think it is related to the loading of 'test.js', but if I change it to `var s=$('<img src="image.png"></img>');` the warning message won't show.

2) If the .js file has to be loaded this way, what is the best practice?

*********** Editting ***********

The content of test.js is

```
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('h1'))
```

There is a `h1` in HTML.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file

Comment: That is not a synchronous XMLHttpRequest.  That JS file is probably making one.

Comment: The content of test.js is just `console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('h1'))`, I'm editting this to the main thread.

Comment: Appending a script tag in document does not create XMLHttpRequest. Problem lies somewhere else. The error message must be accompanied by a line number and filename, can you check and post what is causing this error?

Comment: it is this line in jQuery 2.1.4(http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js):
`if (f.open(a.type, a.url, a.async, a.username, a.password), a.xhrFields)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem is relating to `async`

In HTML5: `async`, `defer`, you can tell browser when to run your JavaScript code. There are 3 possibilities:

```
<script       src="myscript.js"></script>

<script async src="myscript.js"></script>

<script defer src="myscript.js"></script>
```

1. Without `async` or `defer`, browser will run your script immediately,
   before rendering the elements that's below your script tag.
2. With `async` (asynchronous), browser will continue to load the HTML
   page and render it while the browser load and execute the script at
   the same time.
3. With `defer`, browser will run your script when the page finished
   parsing. (not necessary finishing downloading all image files. This
   is good.)

I found below answer: [synchronous-xmlhttprequest-on-the-main-thread-is-deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24740773/synchronous-xmlhttprequest-on-the-main-thread-is-deprecated)

> Using jQuery to append a script tag to the document will cause it to
>   load the script with `async:false` and trigger this warning.
>
> ```
> var script = $("<script></script>");
> script.attr("src", player.basepath + "whatever.js");
> $(document.body).append(script);
> ```

Not tested. Just for your information.