# XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome

What meaning of this message:

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of
>   its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help,
>   check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

You may have a new message that will block any feature of my site?

Thanks

Comment: Read this: https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#sync-warning

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this message is displayed when using a synchronous AJAX request.
[Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24740773/synchronous-xmlhttprequest-on-the-main-thread-is-deprecated)

Answer (score 0):

If you use a synchronous ajax request on the main thread it will block your application / webpage until the response is received.

You should use asynchronous requests with callbacks or use Worker-Threads to load the data with XMLHttpRequest. Normally the first solution is the prefered way.