# web2py - Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated

Tags: javascript, jquery, view, web2py, deprecation-warning

All,

Receiving the following warning in console of my web2py app.

The only way that this can be cause is when component is being loaded.

I use the default api for this, and have no custom javascript in the view.

There are many related threads for the particular jquery warning, most popular  listed below as a reference, but this is a specific web2py question.

Regards,
James

P.S.
Related jquery posts:
[link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24639335/javascript-console-log-causes-error-synchronous-xmlhttprequest-on-the-main-thr) 
[link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24740773/synchronous-xmlhttprequest-on-the-main-thread-is-deprecated)

Comment: What does the controller/view code of your component look like?

Comment: `{{include 'web2py_ajax.html'}}
{{=LOAD('content', 'display.load', ajax=True)}}
`

Comment: No, the code of the *component*, not it's parent page.